# how to set fade function with scrollview position

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I have a page and when it scrolling up I need a header part of my page should fade out and when scrolling out it should fade in. I tried to do this with fade in function actually I did it but its using time instead of the position.

The problem is Fade function support the time. I need to to fade away with position

I have tried

```
      <ScrollView Scrolled="ScrollView_OnScrolled">

   <StackLayout >
    <AbsoluteLayout x:Name="AbsoluteLayout1"   >

       // header part

            </AbsoluteLayout>


    <StackLayout >
        // body part

     </StackLayout>        
</StackLayout>
```

In my code behind i tried this

```
    private double previousScrollPosition = 0;

  private async  void  ScrollView_OnScrolled(object sender, ScrolledEventArgs e)
    {
        if (previousScrollPosition < e.ScrollY)
        {
            //scrolled up
            previousScrollPosition = e.ScrollY;           
            await AbsoluteLayout1.FadeTo(0.2, 400, Easing.SinInOut);
          }

        }
        else
        {
            //scrolled down

            if (Convert.ToInt16(e.ScrollY) == 0)
                previousScrollPosition = 0;
            await AbsoluteLayout1.FadeTo(1, 400,Easing.SinIn);          
        }
       }
```

How to set fadeaway with scrolling position on xamarin forms

Comment: Are you trying to achieve [this](https://assets.materialup.com/uploads/3629dd12-638c-4dd2-ab1a-9c15ee72a869/687474703a2f2f692e67697068792e636f6d2f336f3835784a4a4e727654647848586439432e676966.gif)

Comment: @G.hakim Similar, Also I did that part now I want to fade away it when scrolling up(In that image the awesome Title part) and fade in when scrolling down

Comment: So basically this is the effect you want right?

Comment: @G.hakim is it fading away when scrolling up? I need the header part to fade away when scrolling up

Comment: In that image is it fading or not is my question!?

Comment: @G.hakim  no, it is not fading away. I need to set when the position changed the header part opacity should change according to that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here what I found on this question

```
    public static async void CustomAnimation(double position, AbsoluteLayout name)
    {
        for (double i = 0; i < 81; i++)
        {
             Change here how you want to change the opacity(can make custom animation)
            var x = 1 - 0.0125 * i;

            if (position == i)
            {
                await name.FadeTo(x, 30, Easing.SinOut);

            }
        }
    }
```